# Migration PG version from 13 to 14 on AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, backup, upgrade

I am pretty new to AWS and we plan to migrate our Postgres version from 13.7 to 14.3, to be able to use a new function for generation UUIDs.

If I correctly understood, the first step is taking a backup. After the upgrade process is done on AWS, we should only reindex data

```
REINDEX DATABASE database_name
```

and

```
ANALYZE
```

to build query plans

and then to upgrade extensions

```
ALTER EXTENSION extension_name UPDATE TO ‘new_version’
```

Any caveats in the process? We're just in MVP and don't have to much data, but we don't want even small number of users to experience downtime or slowdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the AWS-recommended process for upgrading major engine versions - [How to perform a major version upgrade](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.html#USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.MajorVersion.Process). I don't think you need to run `REINDEX`.

From my experience, the engine upgrade takes up to half an hour to complete. Your DB will be unavailable during the upgrade. Consider using RDS blue/green deployments to minimize the downtime - https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/blue-green-deployments.html.